# Is it possible to only run a particular line of Python code instead of the whole script in Sublime Text?

Tags: python, sublimetext2

Suppose I have a following Python script opened in Sublime Text, is it possible to run the line of 'titles' only, instead of the whole script?

```
X=lda.datasets.load_reuters()
vocab=lda.datasets.load_reuters_vocab()
titles=lda.datasets.load_reuters_titles()
```

Comment: Not an aswer about sublimetext (not using it since ages!), but you may consider jupyter notebook: it lets you write the code in cells and the lets you execute a single cell (i.e. the one with the three lines)

Comment: not related to sublimetext, but [pdb](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html) can do that